# Customize Kibana 7.16 logo or inject custome css or js

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I'm having a hard time to find the scripts where the logo is defined (navbar logo, startup, login logo ...).
I've been looking around for ways to change the logo but apparently the kibana project structure has changed significantly in the last builds.
is there any way to inject a custom js or css to change the default logo of Kibana ?

Comment: This is still [work in progress](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/75377)

Comment: Yeah i saw the thread, but i think there's a workaround to achieve this

Comment: Yes, probably, but it depends on the version and might break after an upgrade.

Comment: I hate to have to say this, but Opensearch Dashboards (was OpenDistro) [provides this facility](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/dashboards/branding/)

Comment: btw i managed to change the css markup in legacy_light_theme.css file. it's not the best solution, but it gets the job done for the moment.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out